# How to create project specific Node development environment?

Tags: node.js, versioning, development-environment

In the Python world, there are `virtual-env` and `conda-env` for creating isolated, project specific environments. This is very handy when you are involved with multiple projects: different requirements, different start times, moving at different speeds, etc.

How is this use-case handled in the Node world? What are best-practices? **Do Node specific tools exist to create and manage isolated project specific environments?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Requests for tools are explicitly off topic here on SO, and "best practices" are generally too broad or based on opinions.

Comment: as mentioned, off topic. but this should be helpful for you https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

Comment: In general, node environments are managed per project *by default* since dependencies are installed in the `node_modules` folder in each project.  The only thing shared is the runtime itself.  Ideally, that one version works for everything, but in the cases it doesn't, you can either install multiple runtimes or use something like nvm.

Comment: I think the _docker_ will help you in this case. In node world there are not such packages as _virtualenv_ or _conda_ for node specific project :(

Comment: Josh is right, projects are handled correctly by default, so it doesn't need things like virtual-env - that's just a band-aid over a big flaw in how Python is used. If you need to specify which version of node to use, you can use the engines property in package.json, everything else is per-project by default

Comment: @josh3736 that's an answer. If you submit it I'll mark it. Perhaps the puritans will disagree. Sure I used the word best-practice, but the nature of the question is simply a *how* programming question.